# How to I use my firebase variables as an integer?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple program that you can post/accept games then report back the score. I am having an issue of updating the score as information stored in firebase is stored as a string. How do I take my score as an integer to add to it?

```
        if (selfScore > oppScore) {
        var ref = new Firebase('taken out');
            var selfRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + (selfKey));
            selfRef.update({
                "tScore":  ("tScore" + 3)
            });
        }
```

Ideally, the score would take the previous score and add 3 but this is not the case. I'm new to firebase so if this is obvious, my bad. An edit to clarify when I remove tscore and just have tScore: +3 it just changes tScore to 3, it doesn't add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make some operations on field value within the `update()` method. So you should first **read** the value from the database and then **update** the record with the new value.

The best approach is to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) for such operation, which will automatically do the read/write operation and, in addition, ensure "there are no conflicts with other clients writing to the same location at the same time".

You would then do as follows:

```
var selfRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + selfKey + "/tScore");
selfRef.transaction(function(currentValue) {
  return currentValue + 3;
});
```

Comment: FYI, you may have a look at this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html?linkId=65365800. It is for Firestore though (no the Realtime Database).